# 'cmake rebuild_cache' for *just* a subdirectory?

Tags: build, cmake, build-process, meson-build

I have an issue with the generation of makefiles stage of CMake being slow which is similar to this unanswered question:

*[CMake is slow to generate makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701628/cmake-is-slow-to-generate-makefiles)*

My project is made up of a top level `CMakeLists.txt` file which uses `add_subdirectory()` to add various subprojects for individual library and executable components.

For a given component, the `CMakeLists.txt` file contains something like:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED
  sourceFile1.cpp
  sourceFile2.cpp
  ...
)
```

I can build just the contents of that directory using:

```
make mylib
```

If I modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the sub-directory (which I've been doing a lot as part of a migration from pure Makefiles to CMake) then run `make` it correctly re-runs CMake to update the configuration as if I'd run `make rebuild_cache`.

However, I notice that it in fact reconfigures the **entire** project. I really want for CMake to be clever enough to know it only needs to regenerate the Makefile in the current directory and sub-directories.

**Is there a better way to structure a CMake project to achieve this?**
I see some people use *project()* for each CMakeLists.txt in each sub-project. In general, is this a good idea?

**Alternatively/additionally is there some way to speed up the generation step of CMake?** (currently I have 60s+)

Bonus points if you want to discuss why CMake itself should or shouldn't be able to run in parallel (imagine a `cmake -j`).

---

I've added the meson-build tag as a modest bounty, but alone it hasn't yet attracted enough attention to warrant an answer. It's this kind of problem that might cause people to switch to build systems to meson-build (assuming it doesn't have similar problems) or something similar.

It is possible that the correct answer is it can't be done without modifying the source to CMake. To earn the bounty though I require an explanation in terms of how CMake works and/or where it is flawed.

---

**Clarification:** It is the *generation* step that is slow in my case. The configure itself is quick enough, but CMake hangs for a quite a while between outputting *"-- Configuring done"* and *"-- Generating done"*.

For a full cache rebuild I run:

```
make -n rebuild_cache
```

```
Running CMake to regenerate build system... 
using Makefile generator
-- FOOBAR_VERSION: 01.02.03
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/brucea/work/depot/emma/main/cmake
real 74.87
user 1.74
sys 1.02
```

Under the hood this runs:

```
cmake -H<source dir> -B<build dir>
```

I presume `-B` is a synonym for `--build`. Neither option is described correctly in the documentation. `-H` is the root of the source directory (not the same as `--help` as the documentation would have you believe).

It's fast to get to the output of *"Configuring done"*, but slow from there:

For example,

```
15:44:14 execve("/usr/local/bin/cmake",
>grep Generating cmake_strace.log
>grep "Configuring" cmake_strace.log
15:44:15 write(1, "-- Configuring done\n", 20-- Configuring done
15:45:01 write(1, "-- Generating done\n", 19-- Generating done
>grep "Build files" cmake_strace.log
15:45:22 write(1, "-- Build files have been written"..., 77-- Build files have been written to:
```

If editing a single CMakeLists.txt file in a subdirectory, and 
then running `make -n`, it runs:

```
cd /home/project/cmake && /usr/local/bin/cmake -H/home/project/cmake -B/home/project/cmake --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
```

--check-build-system is another undocumented option.

The effect is the same - regenerate the whole build system, not just the current subtree.
There is no difference in behaviour between an in-source and an out-of-source build.

If I run a trace, e.g.:

```
strace -r cmake --trace -H/home/project/cmake -B/home/project/cmake 2>&1 | tee cmake_rebuild_cache.log
sort -r cmake_rebuild_cache.log | uniq
```

The majority of time spent seems to be spent on (or between) open, access & unlink calls.

The length of each task is quite variable, but the huge number of them builds up.
I have no idea what the Labels.json and Labels.txt files are about (something internal to CMake).

One run:

```
    49.363537 open("/home/projectbar/main/test/foo2bar/CMakeFiles/test2.foo2bar.testViewingSource1.dir/build.make", O_RDONLY) = 5
     1.324777 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/performance/CMakeFiles/performancetest.chvcthulhu.testChvcthulhuPerformance2.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.907807 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/foo2bar/CMakeFiles/test2.foo2bar.testPeripheralConnection2.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.670272 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/src/foo2bar/Foo2Bar/CMakeFiles/foo2bar_lib.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.600272 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/foo2bar/testFilesModel2.ok", R_OK) = 0
     0.599010 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/hve2snafu/testInvalidByte2c.ok", R_OK) = 0
     0.582466 read(5, "openjdk version \"1.8.0_71\"\nOpenJ"..., 1024) = 130
     0.570540 writev(3, [{"# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT E"..., 8190}, {"M", 1}], 2) = 8191
     0.553576 close(4)                  = 0
     0.448811 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/snafu2hve/CMakeFiles/test2.snafu2hve.testNoProbes2.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.431559 access("/home/projectbar/main/src/foo2bar/Foo2Bar/CMakeFiles/foo2bar_lib.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.408003 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/lachesis/CMakeFiles/test2.lachesis.testBadSequenceNumber1.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.407120 write(4, "# The set of languages for which"..., 566) = 566
     0.406674 write(3, "# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT E"..., 675) = 675
     0.383892 read(3, "ewingPeriod.cpp.o -c /home/bruce"..., 8191) = 8191
     0.358490 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/cmake/CMakeFiles/mklinks.chvdiff.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Another run of the same command:

```
     2.009451 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/cmake/CMakeFiles/mklinks.lachesis.dir/Labels.json") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
) = 20
) = 19
     1.300387 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/chvedit/CMakeFiles/test2.chvedit.tefooultiMatchFactoringEdit2.dir", R_OK) = 0
     1.067957 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/chvedit/CMakeFiles/test2.chvedit.tefooultiMatchFactoringEdit2.dir", R_OK) = 0
)         = 1
     0.885854 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/src/gorkyorks2bar/CMakeFiles/doxygen.correct.gorkyorks2bar.dir/Labels.json") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.854539 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/reportImpressions/ReportImpressions/CMakeFiles/testsuite1_reportImpressions.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.791741 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/cmake/CMakeFiles/mklinks.bar_models.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.659506 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/cmake/CMakeFiles/mklinks.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.647838 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/libyar/YarModels/CMakeFiles/testsuite1_yarmodels.dir/Labels.txt") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.620511 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/libyar/YarModels/CMakeFiles/testsuite1_yarmodels.dir/Labels.json") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.601942 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/cmake/CMakeFiles/mklinks.lachesis.dir/Labels.txt") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.591871 access("/home/projectbar/main/src/runbardemo/simple_demo/CMakeFiles", R_OK) = 0
     0.582448 write(3, "CMAKE_PROGRESS_1 = \n\n", 21) = 21
     0.536947 write(3, "CMAKE_PROGRESS_1 = \n\n", 21) = 21
     0.499758 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/foo2bar/CMakeFiles/test2.foo2bar.testInputDirectory1.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.458120 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/yak2dcs/CMakeFiles/test2.yak2dcs.testsuite2.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.448104 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/reportImpressions/CMakeFiles/test2.reportImpressions.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.444344 access("/home/projectbar/main/src/bananas/CMakeFiles/bin.bananas.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.442685 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/rvedit/CMakeFiles/test2.rvedit.tefooissingOptionValue.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.425604 unlink("/home/projectbar/main/test/listdcs/CMakeFiles/test2.listdcs.testListCalls5.dir/progress.make.tmp") = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     0.391163 access("/home/projectbar/main/src/siedit/CMakeFiles/siedit.dir", R_OK) = 0
     0.362171 access("/home/projectbar/main/test/foo2bar/CMakeFiles/test2.foo2emma.testHowResults6.dir", R_OK) = 0
```

Note the Ninja generator is much faster (though still not brilliant).
For example,

```
/usr/bin/time -p ninja rebuild_cache
```

```
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/ams2yar/ams2yar. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/vox/vox. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/bananas/bananas. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/fidlertypes2fidlerinfo/fidlertypes2fidlerinfo. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/mkrundir/mkrundir. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/runyar/runyar. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/runyardemo/runyardemo. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
[1/1] Running CMake to regenerate build system...
Generator=Ninja
-- FOO_VERSION: 01.02.03
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/project/cmake/build
real 12.67
user 1.01
sys 0.31
```

Note that the project is not quite ready for Ninja yet as there are errors like:

```
ninja: warning: multiple rules generate ../src/runfoobardemo/runfoobardemo. builds involving this target will not be correct; continuing anyway [-w dupbuild=warn]
```

and

```
ninja: error: dependency cycle: ../src/foobar -> ../src/foobar/CMakeFiles/foobar -> ../src/ams2emma/foobar
```

to be resolved. This question is really about why the *Makefile* generator is slow. I'm not sure if the problems Ninja shows are useful hints here or red herrings.

---

Building CMake with more optimisations does not help.

Based on my trace output it and the output of time, it is unlikely that it would.
The user time and therefore time spend within the CMake code itself is quite low.
(see e.g. *[What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)*).

Here's what I tried for completeness:

```
export CXX_FLAGS="-O3 -ftree-vectorise -msse2"
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
```

Actually using a more optimised CMake *does* make the configure part faster,
but in my case it is the **generate** part that is slow.
It would appear from the timing that this step is somehow I/O bound.

---

I decided to investigate Florian's idea that using memory insteam of file stream for temporary files might make a difference.

I decided to try the easy route and hacked CMake to write .tmp files to a RAM disk instead.

I then went the whole hog and tried generating the build system on the RAM disk:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
/usr/bin/time -p cmake -H/<source> -B/mnt/ramdisk/build
```

I was very surprised to find this makes no difference at all to the wall clock time:

```
real 59.61
user 1.55
sys 0.62
>du -sh /mnt/ramdisk/build/
4.4M    /mnt/ramdisk/build/
```

Similarly with ramfs:

```
real 51.09
user 1.58
sys 0.50
```

What could be happening here? I was guessing sub-processes, but I can't work out which sub-processes are consuming the wall clock time if any of them are. They look to be very short lived.

---

For completeness, here is some output from perf (CMake built with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`):

```
perf record -g --call-graph dwarf cmake -H<source> -B<build>
perf report -g graph
```

```
Samples: 17K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 14363392067
  Children      Self  Command          Shared Object                 Symbol
+   65.23%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] do_cmake
+   65.02%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmake::Run
+   60.32%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] main
+   59.82%     0.00%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] __libc_start_main
+   57.78%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] _start
+   55.04%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmGlobalUnixMakefileGenerator3::Generate
+   54.56%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmake::Generate
+   49.90%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmGlobalGenerator::Generate
+   38.87%     0.02%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3::Generate
+   18.65%     0.01%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileTargetGenerator::WriteTargetBuildRules
+   17.05%     0.02%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::ExecuteCommand
+   16.99%     0.01%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::ReadListFile
+   16.84%     0.01%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmCommand::InvokeInitialPass
+   16.79%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::Configure
+   14.71%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::ConfigureSubDirectory
+   14.67%     0.05%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMacroHelperCommand::InvokeInitialPass
+   14.27%     0.02%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileUtilityTargetGenerator::WriteRuleFiles
+   13.91%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmGlobalGenerator::Configure
+   13.50%     0.05%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Convert
+   13.48%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmAddSubDirectoryCommand::InitialPass
+   13.46%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::AddSubDirectory
+   12.91%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmGlobalUnixMakefileGenerator3::Configure
+   12.82%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmake::ActualConfigure
+   10.90%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmake::Configure
+   10.55%     0.02%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileTargetGenerator::WriteObjectRuleFiles
+   10.35%     0.09%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3::WriteMakeRule
+    9.76%     0.03%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileTargetGenerator::WriteObjectBuildFile
+    7.97%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileLibraryTargetGenerator::WriteRuleFiles
+    7.93%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefileExecutableTargetGenerator::WriteRuleFiles
+    7.88%     0.00%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3::WriteLocalMakefile
+    7.68%     0.02%  cmake            [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] sysret_audit
+    7.60%     0.05%  cmake            [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] __audit_syscall_exit
+    7.40%     0.08%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmsys::SystemTools::CollapseFullPath
```

And *perf report -g graph -no-children*:

```
+    2.86%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] _int_malloc
+    2.15%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
+    2.11%  cmake            [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] find_next_bit
+    1.84%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] __memcmp_sse4_1
+    1.83%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] _int_free
+    1.71%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::__ostream_insert >
+    1.18%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string
+    1.13%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] malloc
+    1.12%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__ArgumentNeedsQuotes
+    1.11%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::string::compare
+    1.08%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] __strlen_sse2_pminub
+    1.05%  cmake            cmake                         [.] std::string::_S_construct
+    1.04%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmsys::SystemTools::ConvertToUnixSlashes
+    0.97%  cmake            cmake                         [.] yy_get_previous_state
+    0.87%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__GetArgument
+    0.76%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::basic_filebuf >::xsputn
+    0.75%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::string::size
+    0.75%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__SkipMakeVariables
+    0.74%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__CharNeedsQuotesOnUnix
+    0.73%  cmake            [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] mls_sid_to_context
+    0.72%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string
+    0.71%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__GetArgumentSize
+    0.65%  cmake            libc-2.17.so                  [.] malloc_consolidate
+    0.65%  cmake            [kernel.kallsyms]             [k] mls_compute_context_len
+    0.65%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmOutputConverter::Shell__CharNeedsQuotes
+    0.64%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmSourceFileLocation::Matches
+    0.58%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmMakefile::ExpandVariablesInStringNew
+    0.57%  cmake            cmake                         [.] std::__deque_buf_size
+    0.56%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmCommandArgument_yylex
+    0.55%  cmake            cmake                         [.] std::vector >::size
+    0.54%  cmake            cmake                         [.] cmsys::SystemTools::SplitPath
+    0.51%  cmake            libstdc++.so.6.0.20           [.] std::basic_streambuf >::xsputn
```

Comment: `project()` modifies neither parsing flow nor makefile generation flow. It just adds several CMake variable's definition.

Comment: I had a similar problem and rebuilding CMake itself with a lot more optimization options then the normal distributions did reduce my configuration time from about 20s to less then 1s. Which host system do you use? Another alternative would be to divide a big project into sub-projects using `ExternalProject_Add()` (see e.g. my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443164/cmake-share-library-with-multiple-executables/33448011#33448011)), but this would increase the initial configuration step duration. Last there is always the possibility of binary delivery (pre-compiled libraries).

Comment: And did you see [CMake Performance Tips](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Performance_Tips)? Because I think this being more a configuration step issue then having a problem with the generation step (just writing the files is normally pretty fast). Can you please try the [Investigation/profiling methods](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Performance_Tips#Investigation.2Fprofiling_methods)? Simply because the configuration step duration mainly depends on what you do in your `CMakeLists.txt` files.

Comment: I thought about externalProject_add() but really the subprojects are not external. They are part of the same source tree. In particular they share the same configuration and are strongly coupled (as in your answer). Is it considered good "modern cmake" practice to use ExternalProject_Add() as a workaround in this case?

Comment: Note that I have looking at the performance tips and using trace / strace. I've even poked into the source of cmake a little. Nothing obvious leapt out and I haven't had a chance to delve deeper.

Comment: @BruceAdams Thanks for the details. I think I can write answer with some details on the inner workings, but I would need some more information on your host system, your toolchain and which CMake version/distribution you are using. Could you please add also your `cmake ...` command line call? And would it be - as a last resort - an alternative to switch to [Ninja Build](https://ninja-build.org/)?

Comment: I'm not certain on how well externalProject_add would work with ninja.
presumably there would be a toplevel ninja script and one for each externalised subproject.
I believe ninja prefers to have a single ninja script at the top level. I guess it would call out to each subproject okay and just lose a little speed.
I'm less sure how this would interact with make -j (or ninja -j). The separate sub-builds would be unaware of each other. Might this result in a fork bomb?

Comment: @BruceAdams Wow, thanks for the additional details and testing. I've tried to address most of your questions in my answer below. Hope it helps solving your performance issue. Regarding the problems you ran into when switching to `ninja`, those errors look like you should address/solve them even if you are not swtiching to `ninja`. And yes, the idea behind using `ninja` was that it has only to write two files to define the complete project (without the need of splitting it).

Comment: @BruceAdams I've been thinking a while about the `real` and `user`/`sys` timing differences and - also after reading [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53302/why-would-the-real-time-be-much-higher-than-the-user-and-sys-times-combine) - assume something in CMake is waiting for a response from the OS.  But it seems to not be the file I/O. So I looked a little into other possibilities and found only [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801604/how-do-i-tell-what-a-linux-process-is-waiting-for) and [this](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/io-profiling) so far.

Comment: @BruceAdams Maybe we could continue this discussion [in a chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105664/room-for-florian-and-bruce-adams)? I feel it would help going through the implications of some of your findings.

Answer (score 6):

There are so many aspects that define CMake's configuration and generation steps duration (besides what you actually do in your CMakeLists.txt files; it's e.g. your host system, your toolchain and which CMake version/distribution you are using).

So I try to concentrate on the specific questions you have.

**Rebuild/rewrite makefiles for *just* a subdirectory?**

For the start: Using `add_subdirectory()` is good for structuring your CMake code. But you have to keep in mind that you can always change global CMake properties in a subdirectory and that targets inside those subdirectories can have cross-dependencies.

So what does CMake do (considering the "I have touched one `CMakeLists.txt` file in a subdirectory" case discussed here):

- If a `CMakeLists.txt` file is changed it goes through the complete hierarchy of `CMakeLists.txt` files again and rebuilds the build environment again in memory.
- Now it temporarily recreates all the necessary build/make files and checks if they defer from the existing ones (see [`cmGeneratedFileStreamBase::Close()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmGeneratedFileStream.cxx#L162)).
- If a file has changed it replaces the existing one with the new one.

This behavior is necessary because any makefile can change even when only a subdirectory's `CMakeLists.txt` file has changed and it was optimized to prevent unnecessary rebuilds during the actual `make` step (from touched makefiles).

**Is there some way to speed up the generation step of CMake?**

So yes, it does temporarily rewrite all makefiles (which could be slow) and no, you can't minimize this while using `add_subdirectory()` to only the changed subdirectory.

Maybe one possible performance optimization for the future in CMake's own code would be to use memorystreams instead of filestreams for the temporary files.

@BruceAdams tested this by using a RAM disk for the generated makefile environment with no effect.

And yes, the CMake generated `cmake_check_build_system` rule does almost the same as the `rebuild_cache` rule and yes the used `-B`, `-H` and `--check-build-system` options are CMake internal command line options and therefore undocumented (even if often referred to on Stack Overflow, e.g. in one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917454/cmake-how-to-specify-the-version-of-visual-c-to-work-with)).

What helped me to speed-up the configuration/generation was to rebuild CMake itself with a lot more optimization options than the normal distributions and using a 64-bit toolchain instead of the 32-bit versions currently still distributed.

Here are some test results (using the CMake test script found below with 100 subdirectories/libraries) on my Windows PC always using the same MSYS environment, but different CMake compilations of the same CMake source code:

1. Official CMake 3.2.2 version:

   ```
   $ time -p cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   [...]
   real 43.93
   user 0.00
   sys 0.03
   ```
2. Using `mingw32` and `GNU 4.8.1` I rebuild CMake 3.2.2 with

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-O3" -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   ```

   and got

   ```
   $ time -p /c/temp/cmake-3.2.2/MSYS32/bin/cmake.exe -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   [...]
   real 41.37
   user 0.01
   sys 0.04
   ```

   And the same with my antivirus software turned off:

   ```
   $ time -p /c/temp/cmake-3.2.2/MSYS32/bin/cmake.exe -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   [...]
   real 20.98
   user 0.00
   sys 0.04
   ```
3. Using `mingw-w64` and `GNU 5.3.0` I rebuild CMake 3.2.2 with

   ```
   $ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=native -m64 -Ofast  -flto" -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   ```

   and got

   ```
   $ time -p /c/temp/cmake-3.2.2/MSYS64/bin/cmake.exe -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   [...]
   real 25.59
   user 0.00
   sys 0.04
   ```

   And the same with my antivirus software turned off:

   ```
   $ time -p /c/temp/cmake-3.2.2/MSYS64/bin/cmake.exe -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
   [...]
   real 6.95
   user 0.00
   sys 0.03
   ```

To summarize I see two main influences:

**1st**: The configuration step can be speed-up by going for a 64-bit version and optimize for your processor platform (you would certainly have to find a common base [`-march=...` or `-mtune=...`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) for all your project's build PCs).

**2nd**: The generation step can mostly be sped up by searching for possible file I/O bottlenecks outside of CMake. In my case telling the antivirus software to not check the toolchain and build directories each time I read/write to those was really speeding up things.

**Remark**: I confirmed @BruceAdams test results that the [the compiler's auto-vectorization](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) (default for `-O3` or `-Ofast`) is not able to do much about CMake source code's ability to run in multiple processes/on multiple cores.

**Is there a better way to structure a CMake project to achieving this?**

Yes, if you e.g. know that a certain sub-tree of your CMake script code just generates a library and has no dependencies, you could put that part in an external project by using `ExternalProject_Add()`. And yes, [having had similar concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512485/cmake-how-to-setup-source-library-and-cmakelists-txt-dependencies) regarding large CMake projects, this is seen as a good "modern CMake" practice (see also references below).

**References**

- [CMake Performance Tips](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Performance-Tips)
- [CMake: Parallel generation of make files](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-November/059151.html)
- *[GCC: how is march different from mtune?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559275/gcc-how-is-march-different-from-mtune)*
- *[CMake: How to set up source, library and CMakeLists.txt dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512485/cmake-how-to-setup-source-library-and-cmakelists-txt-dependencies)*
- *[Making CMake library accessible by other CMake packages automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)*
- [Use CMake-enabled libraries in your CMake project](https://coderwall.com/p/qk2eog/use-cmake-enabled-libraries-in-your-cmake-project-ii)

**What I used to reproduce your problem**

Just for completeness and if someone wants to check those numbers against his/her own, here is my test code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(CMakeTest CXX)

#set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE 1)

set(_idx 1)

while (_idx LESS 100)
    math(EXPR _next_idx "${_idx} + 1")
    if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib${_idx}")
        file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "lib${_idx}")
        file(
            WRITE "lib${_idx}/lib${_idx}.h"
                "int lib${_idx}_func();"
        )
        file(
            WRITE "lib${_idx}/lib${_idx}.cc"
                "#include \"lib${_next_idx}.h\"\n"
                "int lib${_idx}_func() { return lib${_next_idx}_func(); }"
        )
        file(
            WRITE "lib${_idx}/CMakeLists.txt"
                "add_library(lib${_idx} \"lib${_idx}.cc\")\n"
                "target_link_libraries(lib${_idx} lib${_next_idx})\n"
                "target_include_directories(lib${_idx} PUBLIC \".\")"
        )
    endif()
    add_subdirectory("lib${_idx}")
    set(_idx "${_next_idx}")
endwhile()

if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib${_idx}")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "lib${_idx}")
    file(
        WRITE "lib${_idx}/lib${_idx}.h"
            "int lib${_idx}_func();"
    )
    file(
        WRITE "lib${_idx}/lib${_idx}.cc"
            "int lib${_idx}_func() { return 0; }"
    )
    file(
        WRITE "lib${_idx}/CMakeLists.txt"
            "add_library(lib${_idx} \"lib${_idx}.cc\")\n"
            "target_include_directories(lib${_idx} PUBLIC \".\")"
    )
endif()
add_subdirectory("lib${_idx}")

if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cc")
    file(
        WRITE "main.cc"
            "#include \"lib1.h\"\n"
            "int main() { return lib1_func(); }"
    )
endif()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cc")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lib1)
```

And then - after the first `cmake ..` and `make` calls - doing:

```
$ touch ../lib100/CMakeLists.txt
$ time -p cmake ..
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: [your path here]
real 28.89
user 0.01
sys 0.04
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I'm fully convinced by arguments to use externalProject_Add for *internal* libraries.

I will try it out though and see if the performance justifies the extra complexity.

Essentially that means that add_subdirectory does not scale and yet this is one of the few places where cmake's
language is quite nice.

auto vectorisation will not make your code multi-core, multi-threading or multi-process automatically.

There is hope for that with parallel STL and execution policies but you still have to write you code in
suitable fashion.

Comment: I don't think you've actually solved my problem or completely answered the question but rather than let the bounty go to waste I will award it on the basis of effort.
I'll try with external project add when I have more time and if that works out I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @BruceAdams Thanks. So I will also try to add some results on the CMake recompilation part. And sure, the auto-vectorization can only do so much. And I'll give it a try and rewrite my test code to use `externalProject_Add()` for the libraries and add the measurement results also.

Comment: @BruceAdams I've added my recompilation test results. Going for 64bit and - as I've already done for my build environment paths in the past but had not measured the influence so far - selectively disabling my antivirus software had a significant speed-up effect (85% less for the initial configuration step). I'll try to add some numbers for the `externalProject_Add` usage in the coming days.